# Git- what are the dangers to modifying commit data in .git refs directory

Tags: git

I created a git repository to test some git features out. I learned from a blogpost that branches are stored in `.git/refs/heads/` That the file names were names of branches in your application and each of the files contained the commit sha that the branch pointed to.

Turns out you can replace the commit sha with whatever commit sha exists inside the `.git` repo. When I did this and it worked, I thought to myself this is really wrong and I shouldn't be able to do this, but I could only think of human error being involved. So my questions are kind of two fold.

1. What are some dangers of replacing the commit sha within a git branch/ref file?
2. Is there *ever* a situation where you would want to directly modify the branch files in the `.git` folder? Rather then using git commands to do these behaviors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big future risk of Git changing the way it does these things.  This is not particularly unlikely since Git on Windows has issues with branch name case, e.g., the branch names `a` and `A` are two different branch names on Linux and in Git, but are stored in the same *file* on Windows.  When the branch name is *packed* (stored in `.git/packed-refs`—view the file to see, especially after running `git gc`), these two branches are different on Windows too.  When the branch name is *unpacked*, the two branch names become one, with rather messy consequences.

Aside from future risks, the biggest danger with just dumping a raw hash ID into a `.git/refs/heads/branchname` file is that you could get it wrong: it could be a bogus hash ID, or it could be the hash ID of an object that is not a commit object.  Neither of these is allowed by the normal operation of Git, so various internal bits of Git may assume that branch file contents are valid hash IDs pointing to commit objects.

Otherwise, this is precisely what `git reset --soft commit-specifier` does with whichever branch name `HEAD` is attached-to, and precisely what `git branch -f name commit-specifier` does with a branch name to which `HEAD` is not attached.  So if your goal is to emulate one of those two commands without using that command, you *can* do it (at least today, and until Git does something about the name-case-issue on Windows and similar OSes).

As for this:

> Is there ever a situation where you would want to directly modify the branch files in the `.git` folder?

It's useful for experimentation (to test source code changes to Git, for instance, if you want to see if you've fixed some crash that occurs when a branch name has an invalid hash ID in it).  It might occasionally be useful post-system-crash if Git's own internal arrangements have become corrupted.

Comment: thanks for the in depth answer, exactly what I was looking for. man this git whole is deep

Answer (score 1):

> What are some dangers of replacing the commit sha within a git branch/ref file?

`git gc` could delete something you don't want it to.  I forget the exact rules (and they could change in the future anyway), but the short version is that unreachable objects (blobs, trees, and commits) can be irrevocably deleted.  If a branch points to a hash that leaves a large portion of the commit tree unreachable, you could find yourself losing that data permanently.

> Is there ever a situation where you would want to directly modify the branch files in the `.git` folder? Rather then using git commands to do these behaviors.

I'm not aware of any, but git is designed with the Unix philosophy in mind: it doesn't stop you from doing stupid things because that might stop you from doing clever things.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real danger to it. You're meant to be able to look under the hood of git. The biggest potential problem is that if the commit that that head pointed to isn't accessible any other way, and you replace it with something else, then you might not be able to find the old data and it will eventually get deleted. But there are lots of things (the reflog, remote repositories) to save you even from that. It doesn't hurt to know how to do things manually in case you ever end up with a repo in some inconsistent state that the tools don't want to work with, and you need to attempt a recovery.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What are some dangers of replacing the commit sha within a git branch/ref file?

Modifying files in `.git/refs/heads/` directly *should* be fine, but there is to my knowledge no guarantee that this will remain true. There is also nothing to say that `.git/refs/heads/` contains all or even any branch refs -- they can also reside in a packfile. As you probably already know, you are better of using the built-in tools to update refs. See [git update-ref](https://gitirc.eu/git-update-ref.html), [git symbolic-ref](https://gitirc.eu/git-symbolic-ref.html).

> 2. Is there ever a situation where you would want to directly modify the branch files in the .git folder? Rather then using git commands to do these behaviors.

No, aside from testing the behaviour of Git itself I can think of no reason. If you need to modify them, Git provides enough tooling to do so safely. You can use custom refs to keep arbitrary data in your repository. [git notes](https://gitirc.eu/git-notes.html) is an example of such a usage that has later made it into the standard tooling.